# SQL dynamic date but fixed time query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to write a sql query like the example below, however, I need it to always choose the DateEntered field between the current day's date at 8:00am and the current day's date at 4:00pm. Not sure how to go about this. Can someone please help?

```
SELECT     OrderNumber
    , OrderRelease
    , HeatNumber
    , HeatSuffix
    , Operation
    , COUNT(Operation) AS [Pieces Out of Tolerance]
FROM         Alerts
WHERE     (Mill = 3) 
    AND (DateEntered BETWEEN GetDate '08:00' AND GetDate '16:00')
GROUP BY OrderNumber, OrderRelease, HeatNumber, HeatSuffix, Operation
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TodayODBC varchar(30), @DateFrom datetime, @DateTo datetime
SET @TodayODBC = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 120)
SET @DateFrom = CONVERT(datetime, @TodayODBC + ' 08:00:00', 120)
SET @DateTo   = CONVERT(datetime, @TodayODBC + ' 16:00:00', 120)

SELECT OrderNumber, OrderRelease, HeatNumber, HeatSuffix, Operation,
    COUNT(Operation) AS [Pieces Out of Tolerance]
FROM Alerts
WHERE (Mill = 3) 
AND (DateEntered BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo)
GROUP BY OrderNumber, OrderRelease, HeatNumber, HeatSuffix, Operation
```

The `, 120` specifies ODBC datetime format, which is constant regardless of the locale.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT     OrderNumber
    , OrderRelease
    , HeatNumber
    , HeatSuffix
    , Operation
    , COUNT(Operation) AS [Pieces Out of Tolerance]
FROM         Alerts
WHERE     (Mill = 3) 
    AND (datediff(dd,DateEntered,getdate()) = 0 AND Datepart(hh,DateEntered) BETWEEN '08' AND '16')
GROUP BY OrderNumber, OrderRelease, HeatNumber, HeatSuffix, Operation
```

Comment: This will work, but it is not SARGable on the `DateEntered` column. You should normally look for a solution that compares `DateEntered` against two constant values.

Comment: @ChristianHayter you make a valid point, so I tried your solution and it works as well. Thansk to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SQL Server 2008 you can CAST as either date or time. To get the current date at 08:00 you will use:

```
(CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('08:00' AS TIME))
```

To get the current date at 16:00:

```
(CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('16:00' AS TIME)))
```

Putting this into your query:

```
SELECT OrderNumber
    , OrderRelease
    , HeatNumber
    , HeatSuffix
    , Operation
    , COUNT(Operation) AS [Pieces Out of Tolerance]
FROM         Alerts
WHERE     (Mill = 3) 
    AND (DateEntered 
        BETWEEN (CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('08:00' AS TIME)) 
        AND (CAST(CAST(getdate() AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST('16:00' AS TIME)))
GROUP BY OrderNumber, OrderRelease, HeatNumber, HeatSuffix, Operation
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     OrderNumber
    , OrderRelease
    , HeatNumber
    , HeatSuffix
    , Operation
    , COUNT(Operation) AS [Pieces Out of Tolerance]
FROM         Alerts
WHERE     (Mill = 3) 
    AND (DateEntered BETWEEN DATEADD(hour, 8, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,getdate()))) AND DATEADD(hour, 18, CONVERT(datetime,CONVERT(date,getdate()))))
GROUP BY OrderNumber, OrderRelease, HeatNumber, HeatSuffix, Operation
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work for you

```
 DateEntered BETWEEN dateadd(hour, 8, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)) AND 
                     dateadd(hour, 16, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```

But that would (as your query does) include rows where the time is `16:00:00.000'` but not rows with time `16:00:00.003'`.

If you meant to include all rows **before 17:00** use this instead.

```
 DateEntered >= dateadd(hour, 8, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime)) AND
 DateEntered <  dateadd(hour, 17, cast(cast(getdate() as date) as datetime))
```